# Calling two types of jquery - issue in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Firefox works fine, Opera is great and Chrome works well also. IE is the issue. It seems to be ANY version of IE.

The site is http://s91532.gridserver.com and no matter where you click, it brings down our javascript menu from the top.

When you hover over the images it shows you the correct path and everything but when you click it just drops down the Ministry Index dropdown

I have removed the offending jquery which was an older version and am now just calling the site.js which is the code below:

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   $('p#minguide-link a').click(function(){
      if ($('#index-wrapper').is(':hidden')) {
         $('#index-wrapper').slideDown('medium');
         $('p#minguide-link a').addClass('down');
         return false;
      } else {
         $('#index-wrapper').slideUp('medium');
         $('p#minguide-link a').removeClass('down');
         return false;
      }
   });

   var group_width = $('li#nav_groups ul').width();
   var group_adj = ((group_width*-1)/2)+79;
   var care_width = $('li#nav_care--serve ul').width();
   var care_adj = ((care_width*-1)/2)+79;
   var sermon_width = $('li#nav_sermons ul').width() + 2;
   var sermon_adj = ((sermon_width*-1)/2)+79;

   $('li#nav_groups.current ul').css({"left":"auto", "margin-left":group_adj});
   $('li#nav_care--serve.current ul').css({"left":"auto", "margin-left":care_adj});
   $('li#nav_sermons.current ul').css({"left":"auto", "margin-left":sermon_adj});
});
```

With that alone being called nothing happens. It seems that it is now fixed in IE from what I can tell.

Now how do I get site.js to be called correctly so the menu drops down correctly.

Comment: You should really not be using 2 versions of jQuery!! Remove the older version and post your code that doesn't work with 1.4.2. You're better of fixing that.

Comment: Use 1 version of jQuery, update code dependant on old jquery version.
Otherwise, there is no good awnser.

Comment: I do not see the described behavior in IE8. In IE8, when I click on the images, it seems to try and start some sort of "lightbox" thing, but the thing doesn't work and it puts up an error alert().

Comment: Pointy I have seen that also. I have added the site.js which seems to be reliant upon a call to 1.3 before. If I move the code below the call to site.js it wont work either

Comment: The way the page is set up, with the old jQuery, then that script, then the new jQuery, what'll happen is that the new jQuery will effectively wipe away that initialization block because it will overwrite *everything* the old jQuery set up.

Answer (score 0):

Without any useful information (other than the link), all I can do is point you to this article:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_javascript/

You should be using 1.4.2. I've never ever had a single problem with it. You're calling conflicting versions of jQuery, so just use the better one.

Also, site.js isn't using jQuery in compatibility mode. You should change that first line to

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

not

`$(document).ready(function(){`

EDIT

Your site is running in no-conflict mode. You have to get rid of that `$` at the beginning of site.js. It's throwing an error before anything happens. To fix that, all you need to do is change the very first `$` to `jQuery`. All the other `$`s are fine, though.

Here's site.js in jQuery 1.4.2. Just replace the whole file's contents with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   $('p#minguide-link a').click(function(){
      $('#index-wrapper').slideToggle();
      $('p#minguide-link a').toggleClass('down');
      return false;
   });

   var group_width = $('li#nav_groups ul').width();
   var group_adj = ((group_width*-1)/2)+79;
   var care_width = $('li#nav_care--serve ul').width();
   var care_adj = ((care_width*-1)/2)+79;
   var sermon_width = $('li#nav_sermons ul').width() + 2;
   var sermon_adj = ((sermon_width*-1)/2)+79;

   $('li#nav_groups.current ul').css({"left":"auto", "margin-left":group_adj});
   $('li#nav_care--serve.current ul').css({"left":"auto", "margin-left":care_adj});
   $('li#nav_sermons.current ul').css({"left":"auto", "margin-left":sermon_adj});
});
```

Additionally, I really suggest you look up [jQuery's API](http://api.jquery.com). It's super easy to learn and very intuitively organized/layed out. And searching is a breeze.

Comment: I have removed the call to 1.3 and edited site.js to add your code. Still nothing. IE is working fine but now the menu doesn't drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Matthew, replace the jquery 1.3 script tag for the jquery 1.4 script tag, make sure all other script tags are placed AFTER the jquery script tag ;)

Comment: I have already tried it, it doesn't work. And it would be calling 1.4.2 twice still

Answer (score 0):

I would echo the strong recommendation that you make everything work with the up-to-date version of the library, but you might try this: include the old jQuery, then right after that line add this:

```
<script>
  jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

And then include a modified site.js file, changed as follows:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  // existing code
});
```

Comment: Okay so this helped in terms of allowing the menu to come back wdown when pressed. BUT, it now shows weird things in IE7. So I click on the drop down and it seems its loading a picture. BUT when I click on one of the buttons on the right it brings down the menu.

Darned JS!

Comment: the use of the 1.3 is killing me but I need to load something for the drop down menu.

Comment: @Matthew well, I feel your pain, but I think you've just got to choose: the pain of hacking around to make things work with 2 jQuery versions, or the pain of hacking around to make things work with 1.

Comment: would love to make it work with one, but I have no idea how to do that. I can find my way around CSS fine but JS is way out of my league.

If I get rid of one, I assume that site.js is not a full javascript?